# Can't connect my Java App with my SQL Database

Tags: java, mysql, mysql-connector

I am having this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.msql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:12)
```

And this is my code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        Statement sql;

        ResultSet rs;
        Class.forName("com.msql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");

        sql = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        rs = sql.executeQuery("select*from persoane");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("id=" + rs.getInt("Id") + ", name= " + rs.getString("name") + ", age=" + rs.getInt(3));
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why.

I created my project, I went to Project, Project Properties, Libraries, Add External Jars
and added mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin

Answer (score 4):

Typo:

```
Class.forName("com.msql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

should be

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    ^
```

which can be simplified to

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

In fact this statement can be omitted completely since `MySQL` uses a `JDBC` [type 4 driver](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/gbsor/index.html)